# Audio streaming and audio download using rails, nginx, and puma server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I am trying to stream a static audio file and then download the same by doing some basic validations such as validating mobile number etc. I am using nginx+rails 4 + puma server for the same.

Request lands at Nginx, then Rails server (I do some basic validation) then use the send_file code(mentioned below) to send file to nginx back and then streaming/download start.

Issue is I am not able to stream the song plus some XL-Redirect related error is coming in nginx. Your help will be highly grateful as I need to stream large amount of songs i.e. high TPS i am looking forward. So, what's the best possible way.

RAILS CODE  SNIPPET:

```
  file_path = "/home/Co001.mp3"
  aFile = File.new(file_path)
  response.header['Content-Type'] = tone
  response.headers['Content-Length'] = File.size aFile
  file_name = "ringtone.mp3"
  send_file(aFile,
            :filename => file_name,
            :type => "tone")
```

Nginx conf snippet:

```
keepalive_timeout  75 20;

# Virtual Host Configs
include /usr/local/nginx/mime.types;
upstream xyz {
# Path to Puma SOCK file
        server unix:/home/ruby/rails_workspace/xyz/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
        listen 1212;
        server_name xyz.pqr.com;
        root /home/ruby/rails_workspace/xyz/public/;
        #index index.html;

        location / {

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
                #proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping ^/*=/$1;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
        # Logging --
        access_log  /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log;
        error_log  /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log notice;
        error_log  /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log error;

        # serve static files directly
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|mp3)$ {
        access_log      off;
        expires         30d;
        }
}
```

Looking forward for support from your end. Thanks in advance.